# Criar arquivo de projeto como .psd, .sln, um próprio, etc

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como funciona a criação desses tipos de arquivos, sln, psd, arquivos de projetos, psd do photoshop, sln do visual studio, quero criar um próprio tipo de projeto meu, tentei pesquisar no Google, mas, não soube como e não obtive resultados de meu interesse, atualmente estou usando C# sou iniciante na linguagem.

Comment: Depende do objetivo. Se colocar qual é ele, der detalhes, podemos responder, caso contrário, não para lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome desse processo é *associação de tipo de arquivo*. Basicamente funciona desta maneira:

- Um programa associa uma dada extensão (por exemplo `*.minhaExtensao`) a um programa (ex. `C:\Programas\minhaExtensaoEditor.exe`) junto ao Windows.
- Quando o usuário executa um duplo-clique no arquivo `D:\teste.minhaExtensao` o Windows irá procurar em um armazenamento local chamado *Registry* por alguma chamada associando a extensão a um programa - e, neste caso, essa associação é encontrada.
- Windows então tentará executar o seguinte comando:

  ```
  C:\Programas\minhaExtensaoEditor.exe 'D:\teste.minhaExtensao'
  ```
- O programa `minhaExtensaoEditor.exe` é chamado, e um parâmetro informando o arquivo a ser aberto é recebido.

(O processo é um pouco mais complicado do que essa sequência, porém ela ilustra os passos básicos.)

Comment: Ajudou bastante, muito obrigado, só queria pedir, se você tem algum link, ou algo do tipo que contenha algum conteúdo sobre, quero estudar mais a fundo isso, pra um projeto próprio, meio que um passa-tempo.

Preciso aprender principalmente a criar um arquivo, onde posso salvar vários valores, tanto como imagem e código, tava pensando em fazer algo parecido com o SLN do visual studio. Bom sei que é difícil nem nada acontece na noite pro dia mas quero me dedicar a estudar isso, tenho 16 anos e quero ir estudando programação.

Comment: @AdelsonRocha Exemplo funcional aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application

Answer (score 0):

Arquivos PSD são criados dentro do próprio Photoshop, ao criar um novo arquivo, enquanto os SLN são criados junto com as solutions do Visual Studio.